# google map draw route between source and destincation in web application using java and jsp

Tags: java, google-maps, jsp, google-maps-api-3

I am working in java,jsp.  I want to know how to draw google map to display routes between different locations.

**for example:**

> If there are 1,2,3,4,5 addresess pins on map, I click on the 2nd one and
> then click on 5th one so it will find out the route to go from 2nd to 5th
> and then onwards if I click on 3rd it will find the route from the 5th to the
> 3rd
>
> route will be like (2 **-->** 5 **-->** 3)

Please help me out with this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either store your locations in waypoints, or, you can have multiple routes. Note that if you use the waypoints approach, be sure you set `optimizeWaypoints: false,` to that it won't mess up your click order.

I have a demo with the waypoints approach
http://jsfiddle.net/6grw5dre/

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @kaho buddy, If i came across with any doubt will ask you. please help at that time.